# How to expand an Excel hierarchy by default

Tags: excel, ssas, powerpivot, olap

By default, in Excel when you add in a hierarchy it collapses it by default. For example:

[image]

Is their an option whereby the attributes/fields in the hierarchy are expanded by default?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option now.

You can tune only the following default options: [Set PivotTable default layout options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-pivottable-default-layout-options-efd8569c-f07a-43c1-9db2-4f2912a0f94e)

Maybe in future releases expanding/collapsing default behavior will be changed.